# Custom Post Type / Tab Limit

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I've created a site with **nine** (gulp) custom post types. It's a huge site unsurprisingly.

The 9 post types fit on the admin menu but I was wondering if there is a limit to the number of extra post types you are allowed in WordPress?

Say this because when enabling PollDaddy that adds two more tabs (Polls and Ratings) which then hides two of my custom post types from the menu.

Anyone know if there's a limit and how/if I can increase it?

I may try adding a 10th custom post type and see if that displays

Comment: Try, find out, and let us know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably due to clashes in the `menu_position` argument when registering a post type. Try editing those to values between the standard multiples of 10 and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: +1, and to understand what is happening better read the source code http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/menu.php#L121

Comment: Yes, that was it. Had the `menu_position`'s in an order from 25 - 33 so PollDaddy must use two of those. Boosted them all by 10 and now they're all showing.